# Number guesser print wrong when you get it right

Tags: python

So I am making a Number Guesser and when I get it right it prints the "wrong" statement can someone help me please?

```
#randomly select number

import random

#Selects number

numbers = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50

#tell the user to pick a number

guess = input("I am think of a number between 1 and 50, Guess what number ")

num = random.choice(numbers) #selecting the number

#prints if you got it right

if num == guess:
    print("Yes you go it! You rock.")

else:
    print("WRONG! I was thinking of", num, "Try again! Better luck next time.")
```

Comment: `guess` is a string and `num` is a int. They won't be equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you should do

- Cast `guess` to an integer `guess = int(input("..."))` or `if num == int(guess)`. (This will solve the problem you have).
- Instead of making a list of numbers and taking a random choice, you should use [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint). `num = random.randint(1,50)`. You can remove the `numbers` line then

Comment: ok I will try that too!

Comment: this worked thank you so much, This means a lot as I am new to python!!!

Answer (score 1):

guess is input i.e its a string by default.

```
if num == int(guess):
```

Comment: Also, you can try ```random.randint(1,50)``` and remove the line ```numbers= 1,2...```